# Show that $f$ is bijective.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Show that $f$, defined in $0<x<s, (s>0)$ as follows:
$$f(x) = {2x-s \over x(s-x)}$$

is a bijective function of this interval in the reals.

To show that it is injective, we assume $f (x) = f (y)$ and after manipulating we find:
$$(y-x)(-s^2+s(y+x)-2xy)=0$$
then $x=y$, right?

And to show that is surjective just take $f(x)=y$ and manipulating we get $$x = {ys-2 \pm \sqrt {4+y^2s^2} \over 2y}$$

Is that right? The result looks kind of ugly, I was not very confident.

Comment: Injectivity: Why $-s^2+s(x+y)-2xy\ne0$?

Comment: I was confused in this part, I didn't know if I needed to consider $−s2 + s (x + y) −2xy = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show the injectivity, here is one way:
$$\frac{2x-s}{x(s-x)} = \frac{2y-s}{y(s-y)}$$
Bringing to a common denominator, we see that
$$(2x-s)y(s-y) - (2y-s)x(s-x) = 0$$
Assume $x\ne y$ but $x>y$, then
$$(2x - s)y(s-y) - (2y-s)x(s-\color{red}y)<0 \\
\left[(2x-s)y - (2y-s)x\right](s-y) < 0$$
Drop the factor $(s-y)$ since it is positive:
$$(2x-s)y - (2y-s)x < 0 \\ 
-sy + sx < 0 \\
x < y$$
Contradiction. Since the case $x < y$ is similar, we must have $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y. \ \ \square$

Answer (score 2):

ANOTHER APPROACH:

Observe that $$f'(x)=\dfrac{2x(s-x)-(2x-s)(s-2x)}{x^2(s-x)^2}=\frac{2x^2-2xs+s^2}{x^2(s-x)^2}=\frac{(x-s)^2+x^2}{x^2(s-x)^2}>0.$$
So, since $f$ is derivable on the interval $(0,s)$, there the derivative is positive, the function is stricktly increasing

Moreover, $\lim_{x\to0^+} f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to s^-}f(x)=+\infty$.

So $f$ maps bijectively $(0,s)$ into $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve it? The book that this question belongs to does not teach derivatives.